# Use MSBuild to deploy latest build of a certain build quality

Tags: deployment, msbuild

**Background:**
Our development team is looking to hand more control to the QA team with regards to deploying candidates to their environment.

**The Process:**

1. Once all Dev tests are complete, build quality is updated to "Ready for Deployment"
2. QA can kick off their "build" which takes the last version of the code, which was already built prior to step 1 and has been flagged as "Ready for Deployment, and pushes it to the QA environment.

**The Question:**
*In MSBuild, how can we select the latest build of "Ready for Deployment" quality to target for deployment?*  Note that there may be subsequent check-ins or builds after the build that was flagged as "Ready for Deployment."  If this is not possible in MSBuild are there other tools which will facilitate this process?

**Final Note:** We have the actual MSBuild deployment completed so this is out of scope for this question, we are only challenged with how to targeted the correct build.

Answer (score 0):

our source code in TFS is branched into 2 separate sides with in a solution. One is DEV and the other is called MAIN. Once I have my changes working in DEV I check in my code. Then I merge the changes into the MAIN branch. The code located in the MAIN branch is used to deploy to QA and I can keep working on the DEV branch without interrupting the QA Build. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that info; we are currently using the Main/Feature branch strategy on another project I am working on.  On this particular project, we are relying heavily on automated unit testing and want the QA team to be able to get latest and greatest code on a whim.  We will be branching on UAT/Production release candidates.